# Django Form Validation and Admin Actions

Tags: python, django, forms, django-admin

I'm working on a project in which I want to do bulk updates of items in my database. I thought it would be best to leverage the Django Admin page for this.

Here is the function and corresponding form I'm using to display the desired action to the user:

```
class AssignIssueForm(forms.Form):
        _selected_action = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.MultipleHiddenInput)
        issue = forms.ModelChoiceField(Issue.objects.filter(category__id = 1))


def assign_issue(self, request, queryset):
    logger_add_report = logging.getLogger('logview.add_report' )
    logger_add_report.debug("In assign_issue")

    if "apply" in request.POST:
        logger_add_report.debug(request)
        form = self.AssignIssueForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            issue_number = form.cleaned_data["issue"]
            issue = Issue.objects.get(id = issue_number)

            for obj in queryset:
                obj.issue = issue
                issue.save()

            self.message_user(request, "Succesfully assign issue %s to the analyses" % (str(issue_number)))
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.get_full_path())

        self.message_user(request, "Unsucessful!")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.get_full_path())

    form = self.AssignIssueForm(initial={'_selected_action': request.POST.getlist(admin.ACTION_CHECKBOX_NAME)})

    return render_to_response("assign_issue.html",  {
                                                        "analyses" : queryset,
                                                        "form" : form
                                                    },
                                                    context_instance=RequestContext(request) )
```

Here is the assign_issue.html file:

```
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}

{% block content %}

<p>Select an issue to apply: </p>

<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}

    {{ form }}

    <p>The following analysis objects will be linked to the above issue:</p>

    <ul>
        {% for analysis in analyses %}
        <li>{{ analysis.id }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="assign_issue" />
    <input type="submit" name="apply" value="Assign Issue" />
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

The above code displays what I want -- I have a dropdown menu to choose the `issue`, and the form on the assign_issue.html directs back to my assign_issue function. However, the problem comes in with the form validation. Here is the output of request.POST that gets passed back in from assign_issue.html.

```
POST:<QueryDict: {u'action': [u'assign_issue'], u'_selected_action': [u'138912', u'138911', u'138910'], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'*snipped*'], u'issue': [u'129'], u'apply': [u'Assign Issue']}>,
```

When this POST data is made into a form -- the line `form = self.AssignIssueForm(request.POST)` --, the `form.is_valid()` call fails. Can anyone shed some light as to why this is occurring? Is it because I have values in the QueryDict, like csrfmiddlewaretoken and apply, that are not in the form?

The code I have here is based off of [this tutorial](http://www.jpichon.net/blog/2010/08/django-admin-actions-and-intermediate-pages/).

Comment: How fails? Can you post the error message?

Comment: There's no error message, its just that the `form.is_valid()` call fails, so it redirects back to the admin page and displays the "Unsucessful!" string.

*EDIT* by "fails" I should say the `form.is_valid()` call returns False

Comment: Try debugging, and see what happens inside form.is_valid() call. There has to be some comparison evaluating to false. If you find out what it is, you will be more close of your answer.